# Turn a list of lists into a dictionary that can be converted to Json

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a list of lists in Python that I need converted to a dictionary or json, my list looks like below:

```
[
 ['user1', 'Administration', 100],
 ['user2', 'Development', 170],
 ['user2', 'Testing', 30],
 ['user3', 'Administration', 95],
 ['user3', 'Development', 400],
 ['user3', 'Testing', 200]
]
```

I need this to look like this:

```
{
    "user1": {
        "Administration": 100
        },
    "user2": {
        "Development": 170,
        "Testing": 30
    }, 
    "user3": {
        "Administration": 95,
        "Development": 400,
        "Testing": 200
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do this? my current loop overwrites the key, I need it to add the respective attributes if the user already exists.

Thank you!

Comment: Please show your effort

Comment: Can we see the current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# import defaultdict to initialize by dictionary
from collections import defaultdict

# our data
ls = [ 
  ['user1', 'Administration', 100], 
  ['user2', 'Development', 170], 
  ['user2', 'Testing', 30], 
  ['user3', 'Administration', 95], 
  ['user3', 'Development', 400], 
  ['user3', 'Testing', 200] 
]

# create final response
d = defaultdict(dict)

# iterate and fill the result
for u, k, v in ls:
   d[u][k] = v

# see if it's correct
print(d)
defaultdict(dict,
  {'user1': {'Administration': 100},
   'user2': {'Development': 170, 'Testing': 30},
   'user3': {'Administration': 95, 'Development': 400, 'Testing': 200}})
```

Comment: Thank you all so much! that solution is so much simpler than the way I was trying to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
data = [
 ['user1', 'Administration', 100],
 ['user2', 'Development', 170],
 ['user2', 'Testing', 30],
 ['user3', 'Administration', 95],
 ['user3', 'Development', 400],
 ['user3', 'Testing', 200]
]

result = {}
for k, sub_k, v in data:
    result.setdefault(k, {}).update({sub_k: v})
```

**Output:**

```
{'user1': {'Administration': 100},
 'user2': {'Development': 170, 'Testing': 30},
 'user3': {'Administration': 95, 'Development': 400, 'Testing': 200}}
```

Comment: @kuro. Thanks did not see that

Answer (score 2):

Short approach with `collections.defaultdict` object:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# data (your initial list of lists)

d = defaultdict(dict)
for uname, k, v in data:
    d[uname][k] = v

print(dict(d))
```

The output:

```
{'user1': {'Administration': 100},
 'user2': {'Development': 170, 'Testing': 30},
 'user3': {'Administration': 95, 'Development': 400, 'Testing': 200}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For easy understanding**

```
user_list = [
     ['user1', 'Administration', 100],
     ['user2', 'Development', 170],
     ['user2', 'Testing', 30],
     ['user3', 'Administration', 95],
     ['user3', 'Development', 400],
     ['user3', 'Testing', 200]
    ]
user_dict={}
for user in user_list:
    user_dict[user[0]]={user[1]:user[2]}
print(user_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'user2': {'Testing': 30}, 'user3': {'Testing': 200}, 'user1': {'Administration': 100}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
d = [['user1', 'Administration', 100], ['user2', 'Development', 170], ['user2', 'Testing', 30], ['user3', 'Administration', 95], ['user3', 'Development', 400], ['user3', 'Testing', 200]]
result = {a:{c:d for _, c, d in b} for a, b in gb(d, key=lambda x:x[0])}
```

Output:

```
{'user1': {'Administration': 100}, 'user2': {'Development': 170, 'Testing': 30}, 'user3': {'Administration': 95, 'Development': 400, 'Testing': 200}}
```